# What does BigInteger.and is doing

Tags: java, biginteger

I have some piece of code where is use BigInteger.and operation and I am not sure what is this doing. In javadoc is written bigIng & bigInt but this doesn help me to. Can someone explain me in this example ?

```
512.and(113078212145816597093331040047546785012958969400039613319782796882727665664)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `and` operation returns the result of performing [*bitwise and*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on binary representations of two big integers. In your particular example, bit number ten is extracted, because the binary representation of 512 is `1000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

`&` in Java is the bitwise and operator. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html for explanations.

```
1 & 1 == 1
0 & 1 == 0
1 & 0 == 0
0 & 0 == 0
```

Comment: so this bigInteger convert to byte array and then do this operations ?

Comment: The `BigInteger` implementation is backed by an `int[]`, which supports `&` just fine.